# Laravel 8 missing parameter

Tags: php, laravel

I'm facing a missing parameter error every time I try and update user. This is the error:

```
Illuminate\Routing\Exceptions\UrlGenerationException
Missing required parameter for [Route: dashboard.users.update] [URI: dashboard/users/{user}] [Missing parameter: user]. 
    (View: E:\ElSharQawy\Projects\Laravel\3\project\resources\views\admin\users\update.blade.php)
```

these are the routes:

(Note that I have a problem with `dashboard.users.update`)
the last one of them

```
Route::get('/dashboard/login',[dashboardController::class, 'login'])->name('admin.login');

Route::post('/dashboard/login',[dashboardController::class, 'save']);
Route::get('/dashboard',function (){return view('admin.inner');})->name('dashboard');

Route::get('/dashboard/posts',[adminPostController::class, 'getPosts'])->name('dashboard.posts');

Route::get('/dashboard/users',[userController::class, 'getUsers'])->name('dashboard.users');
Route::delete('/dashboard/users/{user:id}/delete',[userController::class, 'destroy'])->name('dashboard.users.delete');
Route::post('/dashboard/users',[userController::class, 'addUsers']);
Route::post('/dashboard/users/add',[userController::class, 'addNewUser'])->name('dashboard.users.add');
Route::get('/dashboard/users/{user:id}',[userController::class, 'updateUsers'])->name('dashboard.users.update');
```

and this is the view

```
@extends('admin.inner')

@section('content')

<form action="{{ route('dashboard.users.update') }}" method="post">
    @csrf
    @method('put')
    <div class="mb-3">
        <h4 for="exampleInputEmail1" class="form-label">Name</h4>
        <input value="{{ $user->name }}" type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1"  aria-describedby="emailHelp">
    </div>

    <div class="mb-3">
        <h4 for="exampleInputEmail1" class="form-label">Username</h4>
        <input value="{{ $user->username }}" type="text" name="username" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1"  aria-describedby="emailHelp">
    </div>

    <div class="mb-3">
        <h4 for="exampleInputEmail1" class="form-label">Email address</h4>
        <input value="{{ $user->email }}" type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1"  aria-describedby="emailHelp">
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3">
        <h4 for="exampleInputPassword1" class="form-label">Password</h4>
        <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1">
    </div>

    <div class="mb-3">
        <h4 for="exampleInputPassword1" class="form-label">Confirm Password</h4>
        <input type="password" name="password_confirmation" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1">
    </div>
    @error('password')
    <div class="mb-3">
        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"> please make sure your passwords match</div>
    </div>
    @enderror
    <button type="submit" class="btn-lg btn btn-info">Update</button>

</form>
@endsection
```

and also the view which calls it:

```
@extends('admin.inner')
@section('content')


    <form action="{{ route('dashboard.users') }}" method="post">
        @csrf
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add a user</button>
    </form>
    <div class="mt-5">
        @if ($users->count())
        <div class="my-4">
            <ul class="list-group">
                @foreach ($users as $user)

                    <li class="list-group-item">

                            <a  href="{{ route('dashboard.users.update', $user) }}" class="btn btn-lg btn">
                                {{ $user->name }}
                            </a>

                        <form action="{{ route('dashboard.users.delete', $user->id)}}" method="post">
                            @csrf
                            @method('DELETE')
                            <button type="submit" class="btn ml-2 mt-2 btn-danger">Delete</button>
                        </form>

                    </li>

                @endforeach
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="center">
            {{ $users->links() }}
        </div>


        @else
        <h4>there are no Users</h4>
        @endif
    </div>

@endsection
```

and lastly the controller and the user model

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\admin;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;

class userController extends Controller
{
    public function getUsers(){
        $users= User::paginate(12);
        return view('admin.users.users',[
            'users'=>$users,
        ]);
    }

    public function destroy(User $user){
        $user->delete();
        return redirect()->route('dashboard.users');
    }

public function addUsers(){
    return view('admin.users.add');
}

public function addNewUser(Request $req){
    $this->validate($req,[
        'name'=>['required','max:255'],
        'email'=>['required','email','max:255'],
        'username'=>['required','max:255'],
        'password'=>['required','confirmed']
    ]);

    User::create([
        'name'=> $req->name,
        'username'=> $req->username,
        'email'=> $req->email,
        'password'=> Hash::make($req->password),

    ]);
    return redirect()->route('dashboard.users');
}

public function updateUsers(User $user){
    return view('admin.users.update',['user'=>$user]);
}


}
```

The Model :

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasFactory, Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'username',
        'email',
        'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];



    public function posts(){
        return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
    }

    public function like(){
        return $this->hasMany(Like::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: Parameter is missing  here `route('dashboard.users.update', parameter)`

Comment: Change route to `{{ route('dashboard.users.update',$user) }}`

Comment: i already have in my code put still something is missing

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify user id in the route to update it relevant user.

```
 <a  href="{{ route('dashboard.users.update', $user->id) }}" class="btn btn-lg btn">

Route::get('/dashboard/users/{user}',[userController::class, 'updateUsers'])->name('dashboard.users.update');
```

Comment: Yes i did what u said and it is still giving me the same error

Comment: try removing -> name('dashboard.users.update')

Answer (score 0):

The route is expecting a user:id
and your giving it a $user

```
   <a  href="{{ route('dashboard.users.update', $user) }}" class="btn btn-lg
```

is the user being passed or is it `null`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the user id, the other answers uses the wrong syntax as far as i know, see [implementation](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/ee1e6b4db76ff11505deb9e5faba3a04de424e97/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php#L715).

You have to pass an associative array, with the route parameter as the key and the value as the `$user->id` or `$user`, it will automatically resolved to the `id`.

```
route('dashboard.users.update', ['user' => $user]);
```